# Polygon shape with smooth curved face

Tags: modeling, mesh, geometry, smooth

I am trying to make a polygon shape (hexagon) with a curved face, but I can't smooth out the actual edges of the mesh. [image]. On the left is the mesh before (Shade smooth). On the right is the result I am trying to achieve (shade smooth applied) but as you know shade smooth is not changing the mesh. I want to get a smooth result similar to shade smooth but to be applied on the mesh. I have tried subdivision surface modifier with different options like simple and Catmull-Clark with keeping corners ( because I want the shape to be a hexagon, but unfortunately, it gets distorted. I have tried to subdivide, bevel, edges, and vertices in edit mode, but I couldn't get results similar to the shade smooth (right hex). The desired outcome is hexagon shape with concave surface like this [image]

Comment: Would you mind sketching what you want the shape to be and adding this as image to the question? Do you just want the edges to be rounded off a bit, like beveled? I mean, what exactly am I looking at, is that a cone viewed from its top? And you want to smooth the top?

Comment: It's distorted because you're using triangle topology which is not suited for the subdiv algorithm

Comment: @GordonBrinkmann does that bring more clarity?

Comment: @Gorgious Well I want a hexagon shape with concaved surface. How can I achieve it in Blender?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Create a cylinder with 6 sides:

[image]

- Crease its edges - Shift + E -> 1 in edit mode

[image]

- Add Subdivision Surface modifier with a few subdivisions, extrude a face and un-crease it with Shift+E -> -1. Extruding out is easier to see:

[image]

- Use bevel operation Ctrl + B, then adjust it to be 100% and have a few segments:

[image]

- Scale it to some negative value like -0.4 by hitting S -> Z -> -0.4:

[image]

- Using snap functionality snap it to place:

[image]

- You can also dissolve some edge loops with Ctrl+X to make the transition smoother:

[image]

You could do it with boolean modifier and a scaled sphere to match your drawing exactly, but then it's like this:

[image]

I am not sure this is what you expect, but you could do it this way. It would be better if the sphere used for boolean had number of segments that would be a multiple of 6, so the edges match nicely.

Comment: Martynas you are great! Edge creasing and subdivision surface got me the desired result, and great knowledge about edge control when using subdivision surface!